# Horse back riding for women

Tags: halacha, women, tznius-modesty, animals, travel

Is it permissible for an Orthodox woman to do horseback riding in an ordinary saddle, or does she have to use a sidesaddle? Furthermore, would she be able to use women's trousers made for horseback riding, or does she need to dress in a skirt?

Comment: We do find many verses that mention women riding on horses, donkeys, etc.

Comment: @ba, do we know whether they rode sidesaddle?

Comment: Maria, orthodox Judaism permits the same things for Orthodox women and for other Jewish women (at least in the vast majority of cases). Is there a particular reason you ask whether standard riding would be permissible for, specifically, an Orthodox woman?

Comment: @msh210 a non-orthodox woman is not likely to feel that orthodox understanding of the Halachah is binding on her.

Comment: @SethJ, but the question was whether it's permissible, not whether the woman views it as such.

Comment: @msh210 Yes, but that depends on whom you ask. If you assume, as many here seem to, that any Halachic discussion must be from the Orthodox perspective, then, sure, it's redundant. But if you don't, it makes sense to specify.

Comment: @SethJ, WADR, no, then it makes sense to specify "Is it permissible according to Orthodox Judaism for a Jewish woman to…", not to specify "Is it permissible for an Orthodox woman to…".

Comment: @msh210, Eh. Distinction without a difference to most people, I think.

Comment: @SethJ, well, that's what I meant in the first place, anyway.

Comment: @msh210 ok......

Comment: @msh210 Thank you for asking me. The reason why I want to know if an Orthodox Jewish woman can do standard riding, is that I seek to convert to Orthodox Judaism. Furthermore, I would like to be able to fit into the community, and I do not want to transgress any prohibitions.

Comment: We need to be careful when ruling against women doing ordinary activities such as bike riding. If we rule that no Jewish woman may ride a bike because of tzniut, then a woman who might ordinary become frum will look with loathing on frumkite. Making Torah observant Jews look regressive is the surest way to prevent those who are interested in becoming observant from ever taking Orthodox poskim seriously, despite the fact that not all Orthodox poskim rule against these activities. I'd rather die than live a life where I have to fear a man's gaze.

Comment: In a survey of legal literature using search engines, I found nothing (although I am sure that I missed stuff). Given that (I assume) that horseback riding was a common form of transportation, if there were a carte blanche prohibition for women to ride horses one would assume this to mentioned more frequently in the literature.

Comment: I've heard horseback riding is a problem, but I've always wondered why since we hear so much about our foremothers riding camels, etc., presumably in the regular fashion (although I can imagine some commentaries' saying otherwise). Does anyone know what gives?

Answer (score 4):

Rabbi Barry Freundel (rabbi of Kesher Israel in Washington, DC) said in a Q&A that if a woman is doing an activity more modestly done in pants than a skirt, she should wear women's pants. As examples, he mentioned bicycle riding and mountain climbing.  He said there no longer exists an issue of beged ish with women wearing pants.

Comment: This doesn't answer the sidesaddle issue.

Comment: Should I refrain from answering one because I can't answer the other?
One might be able to make a case that riding a horse is no worse than riding a bike, which he explicitly permits.

Comment: Wearing pants is not about beged ish, it's about showing the shape of the legs. So the suggestion is either VERY loose pants, or pants with a skirt on top.

Comment: @Ariel No it isn't. It's about avoiding occasionally showing the gap between splayed legs. Nothing to do with 'shape' whatever that means. Legs have about the same shape as a light-post.

Comment: Too bad my other comment was removed, but this person proved by his own deeds that his rulings, in these subjects especially, should be ignored.

Comment: @user6591, you are free to think so.  I wrote this answer in 2012, before Freundel's sins were made public.  Should I delete it now?  Is the logic less compelling because of the source?

Comment: @Ze'ev this is not a mathematical equation dependant on logic alone. This is a halachic ruling trying to delicately and ethically balance rules of decency that are not written in stone. This is the epitome of a ruling that depends on the validity of the source.

Answer (score 2):

Rav Avigdor Nevenzahl in Hanhagos uMinhagim 16 writes there is an inyan for a woman to refrain from riding a horse because of a proof from Rashi (Pesachim daf 3a Rashi Ki Amar) by a woman its written "או על הכלי אשר היא יושבת" since it is not appropriate to mention riding or pisuk reglaim regarding a woman. For this reason it is assur for women to wear pants because of pisuk reglayim aside from other issurim.

It seems riding a horse should not be done,but pants are assur,that's how I understood it,see it inside.

Comment: How is pants pisuk raglayim if she is standing? I understand if she is squatting with her legs apart (as she would be if on a horse) then it's pissuk raglayim. But pants by itself isn't.

Comment: I would assume it means the outline is already pisuk reglayim,I do hear the question,but I can see how pants shows the outline too

Comment: I don't know why one say that. Legs together aren't split...

Comment: But you do understand when one walks in,pants each leg is shown separated as opposed to a skirt or cloak of some sort

Comment: Only if you are taking really longs strides. Normal walking isn't pisuk raglayim. If walking was pisuk raglayim we'd make women jump around with their feet together.

Comment: That's your interpretation,you know and I know its a machlokes.

Comment: Machlokes Rishonim vs Achronim, sure.

Comment: Perhaps I'm ignorant, but I am unaware of sources before recent times that interpreted the gemara in *P'sachim* as forbidding wearing pants. Nor am I aware of any non-recent sources (i.e. prior to late Acharonim) who mention this notion of *pisuk raglayim* (in the manner popularly interpreted by the *hamon am* in our day) beyond saying that it's indelicate to speak explicitly about a woman riding astride when it is unnecessary.

Comment: @Fred No woman ever wore pants until recently. And the Arabic ones that did had a dress on top. Besides, there is no reason to assume the Jewish women were dressing in Muslim outfits that pants had to be addressed.

Answer (score 1):

In describing his stay in the city of Messina, [R. Ovadia of Bartenura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obadiah_Bartenura) [writes](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36661&st=&pgnum=6) as follows:

> וראיתי בחופה שנעשתה בהיותי שמה שהוציאו את הכלה אחרי ברכו שבע  ברכות והרכיבוה על הסוס ברחוב העיר וכל הקהל עוברים לפני' ברגליהם והחתן באמצע הזקנים ולפני הכלה אשר היא לבדה על הסוס
>
> At a wedding which took pace near my residence I witnessed the following ceremony. After the seven blessings had been repeated, the bride was placed on a horse and rode through the town. The whole community went before her on foot, the bridegroom in the midst of the elders and before the bride, who was the only one on horseback;
>
> (Neubauer translation)

While not explicitly saying that horseback riding is permitted, he is describing what was evidently an established custom, and he makes no objection nor mention of anyone else objecting on the grounds that women are prohibited from riding on a horse.

(Of course, there may be other details to this incident that we are not privy too.)

Answer (score -1):

Very loose pants are not allowed: First, because many of them are not tznius; and second, poskim don't allow even the ones that are tznius because it would be opening a can of worms/germs etc...

Women are not allowed to horseback ride in front of men regardless, because it's not tznius. Gemorah [Pesachim 3a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=3&format=pdf)-b.

Comment: b"H for cars! Otherwise, apparently women would have to sit at home all day.

Comment: i am not convinced that that is the meaning of the gemara in Pesachim.

Comment: @DoubleAA, how do cars alleviate that problem? http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/women-driving

Comment: @Seth tell me about it... have you seen Rav vosner's tshuva on it? Shevet halevi 4:1:2 I'm kinda embarrassed to link to it in public

Answer (score -5):

I am Orthodox and I did it in jeans on regular saddle. I don't see a problem in that, neither did the women who taught me how to ride.

Comment: Were the women who taught you halachik experts? Are you?

Comment: @Carlita, welcome to mi yodeya, and thanks for sharing your experience! This answer would be more valuable if you could [edit] in your or your teachers' Halachic rationale, communal traditions, or other source for your and their feelings on the subject. Also, please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: Orthodox. I'm not sure that you're using that word the same way many of the users here do.

Comment: @HodofHod How do you figure?

Comment: @DoubleAA Facebook profile from user's website.

Comment: @DoubleAA I think that could have been asked less sarcastically.

Comment: @mevaqesh It's not sarcastic. It's an incredibly relevant question.

Comment: @DoubleAA I agree to the relevance. The lack of mention of credentials on the part of the answerer suggest a lack thereof. we dont want to come off as elitist by emphasizing this point. I personally prefer the more diplomatic answer of Isaac Moses.